# Comment expliquer le sens et l'origine de l'expression « Allons bon » ?

Tags: expressions, origine-ou-raison, interjections

Typique des expressions et locutions dont on est amenés à comprendre l'usage et le sens en les déduisant des contextes, assez tôt dans la vie car elle est relativement courante (même si faiblissante), cette expression exprime (assez curieusement) la rencontre d'un problème nouveau, ou une mauvaise surprise sans gravité excessive :

> « La chaudière nous a lâchés.
>
> – Allons bon... »

Je me suis trouvé incapable de trouver une explication quelconque, même une simple piste, face à un ami italien parlant un peu français et s'étonnant de l'expression. J'ai dû donner des exemples comme celui ci-dessus pour qu'il tire lui-même le sens du contexte.

Savez-vous d'où elle vient ?

Comment: ne serait-ce pas `Allons! bon!`?

Comment: Non, j'avoue que cette manière de le segmenter sonne étrangement pour moi. Je crois qu'on peut légitimement supposer qu'il y a des variations régionales ou nationales (je veux dire dans la francophonie) et que l'usage que je cite n'est pas utilisé partout. La variante que tu cites a-t-elle le même sens que celui que je décris ?

Comment: Ca me fait penser à "aller bon train" dont on aurait enlever "train" ...

Comment: @EnPassant L'idée est amusante mais.... j'avoue que je ne suis pas encore convaincu.

Comment: @RomainVALERI Feydeau, dans "Chat en poche", Acte III, Scène 6 : "Dufausset - Allons ! bon ! l'autre à présent !" - Trouvé sur internet donc je ne suis pas 100% sûr que ce soit la ponctuation d'origine (j'ai cependant trouvé cette version sur plusieurs sites donc probablement correct).

Comment: @assylias merci d'avoir retrouvé la source. Affaire à suivre, donc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si on se base des définitions respectives des 2 mots sur le Larousse :

> **Allons (interjection)** : Exprime la consolation, l'affection,
>   l'encouragement, l'agacement, l'impatience, etc. *Allons ! ne
>   t'inquiète pas.*

[Définition source de allons](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/allons%C2%A0_/2420)

> **Bon (adv.)** : Renforce une interjection *(Ah bon ! Allons bon !)*

On peut en déduire que l'expression provient de l'interjection qui a été renforcée par le mot "bon" (en tant qu'adverbe). Ainsi pour le reste de l'explication, je vais laisser de côté l'utilisation du mot "bon" pour me concentré sur "allons" en tant qu'interjection.

"Allons" est une interjection d'origine verbale formée sur un impératif(type qui est attesté depuis l'époque médiéval). Pourtant celle-ci n'apparaît qu'à une époque plus tardive du français par rapport au moyen-âge et apparaît officiellement pour la première fois dans le *Dictionnaire de l'Académie Française* dans sa première édition de 1694 avec la définition suivante :

> **allons** : se dit dans le sens d'agir, & s'employe pour exciter à faire quelque chose

On retrouverait donc ce qui est assimilable à une "interjection d'appel".

Voilà je pense que "Allons bon" découle de l'utilisation de l'interjection "allons". Par ailleurs je vous met en lien mes sources, qui fournissent bien plus d'informations que cette version très courte de l'explication. 
[Livre consultable en ligne sur l'origine et l'évolution de l'interjection "allons", démarre à la page 310](http://books.google.fr/books?id=9DI8QBi_e10C&pg=PA311&lpg=PA311&dq=allons%20interjection%20origine&source=bl&ots=q0XI0rOC9X&sig=ljomL3pWHrBLrTlPEl9pzYcf58g&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=_CV2U-jaCsvB0gXDmYCYBw&ved=0CEMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=allons%20interjection%20origine&f=false)

Comment: (+1) Bravo et merci pour cette réponse documentée et pleine de *bon* sens. C'est l'usage adverbial du mot *bon* qui m'avait échappé. C'est maintenant lumineux !

Answer (score 3):

Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait une origine particulière. Il s'agit simplement d'une exclamation de dépit. Néanmoins on peut retrouver des écrits datant du 19e siècle comme sur ce [site](http://www.languefrancaise.net/bob/detail.php?id=42014#38325) où on l'utilise déjà dans ce sens :

–*C'est pas tout, fait le paysan. Dans la chambre que j'vous propose, y a pas d'lit ! –Allons bon ! encore un bâton dans les roues* **1889**.

Answer (score 1):

Si l'on part sur l'hypothèse d'un juron sociabilisé, il faudrait remonter au temps où l’Église toute puissante, aux penchants doloristes établis, pouvait excommunier les parjures.

L'interdiction de proférer n'empêchait pas la formulation sous-jacente :

> *Allons bon* [Dieu ! Une épreuve encore à surmonter]

Comment: Un juron *sociabilisé* ?! Je n'y avais pas pensé ! Si seulement on pouvait trouver quelque chose pour étayer cette hypothèse qui me plait beaucoup... je vais chercher aussi. Merci en tout cas déjà pour cette excellente piste.

Comment: @RomainVALERI la sociabilité est soumise aux pressions des pouvoirs temporels et spirituels alentours. Au travers de la manipulation du langage le publique empiète sur le privé et engage des réactions d'hypocrisie, de révolte ou d'ajustement qui ne sont pas dénuée d'ironie imparable, de rires rabelaisiens ou de sous entendus convenus, et même d'humour : "Je suis viré ? allons bon (qu'à cela ne tienne) me voici entièrement libre de mon temps"